# use data from multiple tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

need some quick help.. i think i'm supposed to use INNER JOIN, but i'm not really sure.

```
List  the employee ID and the full name of the employee who sold or packaged the  
transactions placed by customer Benjamin Jones. Each employee should only show up 
once in your results
```

employeeID, first and last are in the EMPLOYEES table

benjamin jones' memberID is 101 and in the MEMBERS table

memberID and transactionID and soldorpackagedby are in the TRANSACTIONS table

this is what I have to start it off but don't know how to finish it.

```
 SELECT EmployeeID, First, Last
 FROM Employees
 WHERE MemberID = '101'
```

thanks!

Comment: Please format your question properly. Disclaimer: That downvote is not mine.

Comment: A more descriptive view of your table structure would help.  Would be nice to know what links your Employee table to your Transaction table?

Comment: MySql and Sql Server are **different** database engines, but you have tags for both. They both use SQL, but each database has it's own dialect, and answers for one database might not work on a different database. You need to tag your question correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT employees.EmployeeID,
       employees.First,
       employees.Last
FROM employees
JOIN transactions ON employees.EmployeeID = transactions.EmployeeID
WHERE transactions.memberID = 101
GROUP BY employees.EmployeeID, employees.First,  employees.Last ;
```

Comment: this works, but i dont think we've learned about Max() in class so i'm not sure i can use it :/

Comment: Though the question does say "of the employee" it also states "Each employee should only show up once in your results", suggesting that we are interested in multiple employees.  The question would make more sense if multiple employees are to be considered.  Thus 'MAX()' should be avoided.

Comment: removing max..but `group by` all fields available in `select statement`

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
SELECT employees.EmployeeID,
       employees.First,
       employees.Last
FROM employees
JOIN transactions ON employees.EmployeeID = transactions.SoldOrPackagedBy
WHERE transactions.memberID = 101
GROUP BY employees.EmployeeID;
```

Because you are using data from more than one table in this SQL statement you will need to specify which table a repeated field name such as `EmployeeID` will come from, hence `employees.EmployeeID`.  `employee.` is probably not called for in front of `First` and `Last` but I tend to put it in anyway since the habit can help avoid bugs occurring when I am writing more complex statements.

`JOIN` without `INNER`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT` or `FULL` in front is the same as `INNER JOIN` (see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Since the Member's ID is already known and used in the Transactions table, and we are not being asked to refer to any other detail about the member here, then there is no need to link in the Members table.

Without `GROUP BY` the `SELECT` statement will return a record for every time an Employee packaged a Transaction for a Member.  These details would be the same every time.  Using `GROUP BY` would reduce this to just one instance of those details.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: (Assumption) Judging by the question, a Transaction will always be performed by an existing Employee, with their ID being used to help create the record.

Comment: transactions.employeeID doesnt exist, so i did ON EMPLOYEES.EmployeeID = TRANSACTIONS.SoldOrPackagedBy
 which works! however, i get an error on the group by, 
    Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
    Column 'EMPLOYEES.First' is invalid in the select list 
    because it is not contained in either an aggregate function 
    or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Change your GROUP BY clause to `GROUP BY transactions.SoldOrPackagedBy`

Comment: I have modified my answer as per your update.  Can you confirm that you receive the error with this code?  If you do, does removing employees. from in front of First and Last help?

Comment: incomplete `group by` call gives an error without any aggregate functions in `select` statement

Comment: yes same error, but if group by all of the elements in select it works.

Comment: Do you have more than one instance of a certain EmployeeID within the Employees table?